# Confusion between Binary_crossentropy and Categorical_crossentropy

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I am doing binary class classification using deep neural network. Whenever I am using binary_crossentropy my model is not giving good accuracy (it is closer to the random prediction). But if I use categorical crossentropy by making the size of the output layer 2, I am getting good accuracy in only 1 epoch which is close to the 0.90. Can anyone please explain what is happening here?

Comment: Interesting phenomenon. Could you give us some more details about your dataset and / or code which you use?

Comment: I agree with Marcin, some more information would be very helpful. What is the activation function of the output layer when you use binary_corssentropy and when you use categorical_crossentropy? Also, is the class balance in the training set 10 to 1?

Comment: The activation function I am using for both the cases is softmax. The model remains same for both the cases. Only for the case of binary crossentropy the size of the final layer is 1 whereas it is 2 for categorical. Let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I also have this problem while trying to use binary_crossentropy with `softmax` activation in the output layer. As far as I know, `softmax` give the probability of each class, so if your output layer has 2 nodes, it will be something like `p(x1)`, `p(x2)` and `x1 + x2 = X`. Therefore, if you have only 1 output node, it will always be equals to 1.0 (100%), that's why you have close to random prediction (honestly, it will be close to your category distribution in the evaluation set).

Try changing it to another activation method like `sigmoid` or `relu`.

Comment: So this might not be relevant anymore, but just for legacy and clearity reasons: Softmax does not return probabilities, although softmax does ensure that the output of all nodes in your output layer adds to 1 (so in that way it's like a probability).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @TheLaurens!